# dart build: Need to inject an asset from an application into a dependency package

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-build

Background: I have a package with Angular (5.0.0, Dart 2.0.0) components (let's call it *my_components*) that I use in many customer projects (*app_1*, *app_2*, ...). These apps must override some CSS properties (e.g. colors) of almost every component I have to reflect the customers corporate identity. The obvious choice here would be to define the values as SASS variables in a `_variables.scss` file in the *app_n* packages. (I can't use CSS custom properties because IE support is required (I know IE is not officially supported by Angular)) The problem here is that the component scss files must import the `_variables.scss` file, so *my_components* would need a dependency on *app_n*, which isn't possible.

I tried to solve this the following way: In *my_components* I have a file `lib/_variable.default.scss`. The component scss files still contain the line `@import package:my_components/_variables.scss`. I wrote an `InjectAssetsBuilder` that runs on the .default.scss file extension and produces .scss files. The builder is configurable and expects a mapping `'my_components|lib/_variables.scss': 'app_n|web/variables.scss'` in the build.yaml configuration of *app_n*.
The builder is supposed to be triggered by the .default.scss file, then place the customized file right next to it, so it can be found by the component imports.

However, I can't get it to work. If I set `auto_apply` to `all_packages` (in the builder definitions of *my_components*), the builder doesn't receive the mapping configuration (from the build targets section in *app_n*). If I set `auto_apply` to `none`, the builder no longer takes *my_components* as an input, so it can't see and be triggered by the .default.scss file.

If anyone has worked on a similar problem before (or has another idea how *app_n* can inject SASS variables into the *my_components* dependency), I'd love to hear their thoughts. Otherwise, I'd be grateful if someone could explain to me how build configurations are scoped:

1. Why doesn't the `auto_apply: all_packages` builder see the configuration in *app_n*?
2. Why is the builder from the target definition in *app_n* unable to see assets in *my_components*?

If you think I made a mistake with the configuration, I can try to extract a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had some errors in my build.yaml configuration and the builder itself, but I finally got it running. I published my solution on pub: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/inject_assets_builder

The README contains instructions for a full working example.

If you use the same component in multiple places in your app and only want to style some of them, nshanans answer is the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe generating sources into a package that you depend on is a fully supported option in the build system.

In the [angular_components](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/tree/master/angular_components) package we have taken an alternative approach for the components we share across different client apps. We have settled on a system of overriding styles that can be applied to change the appearance.

A shared component is built with a set of good default styles. The shared component also offers a `_mixins.scss` file that contains a set of Sass mixins for client apps to import. The mixins are designed to correctly override all the styles needed to change the theme of a component.

For example here is the [mixin](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/angular_components/lib/material_radio/_mixins.scss) that allows you to change the style of a radio button.